# How to query the individuals with their object properties in sparql (using jena)

Tags: sparql, owl

I created a simple coffee ontology in protege 5.5 which could be used for a company's web site to offer its customers a coffee type through their selections (that's my phD term project). I'm not sure my ontology is all correct. There's no linked data in it. But when I upload my owl file in apache jena to query in sparql, it says 258 triples in it, and when I run the default query for listing subject, predicate and object it seems right to me.
I have 5 classes and 1 subClass in my ontology "Aroma, Base(subClass:Espresso, Chocolate, Tea, Filter Coffee), Sugar, Temperature, Milk". And I have 8 objectProperties "hasAroma, hasNoAroma, hasMilk, hasNoMilk, hasSugar, hasNoSugar, isHot, isCold".
My coffee types like Americano, Latte etc. are my individuals and related the subClass of Baz.
Now, I'm trying to query this individuals with their object properties. The query should give me the result like "Espresso based, hot, with milk, has no sugar coffee". I couldn't find the right sparql syntax for this query. I will put this queries in html with python next.
Is my way to query individuals wrong? Or what can I do to get this result?

Comment: that is basic SPARQL syntax, everything is in the specs: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/ - the subject is given, so you just have to replace this with the URI in your query.

Comment: By the way, showing the ontology in a formal syntax is often easier to understand.

Comment: I checked w3.org earlier and I couldn't understand the syntax. One of my individual is like below. I want to query this with its properties.
kahve_ontolojisi:WhiteChocolateMocha
        a    kahve_ontolojisi:Espresso , owl:NamedIndividual ;
        kahve_ontolojisi:Sertlik3  "Hafif" ;
        kahve_ontolojisi:hasAroma  kahve_ontolojisi:Cikolatali ;
        kahve_ontolojisi:hasMilk   kahve_ontolojisi:Sutlu ;
        kahve_ontolojisi:hasSeker  kahve_ontolojisi:Sekerli ;
        kahve_ontolojisi:isSicak   kahve_ontolojisi:Sicak .

Comment: the syntax is trivial, any tutorial would also show you what to do. Especially when you said your already have the default query `select * where {?s ?p ?o}` - and as I said, the subject of the triple is know, thus, you  put the subject URI in the subject position of the triple pattern: `prefix kahve_ontolojisi: <the URI of the prefix put here> select * where { kahve_ontolojisi:WhiteChocolateMocha ?p ?o}` - done. by the way, the idea of prefixes is to make the whole stuff more compact, so you might rethink about using a shorted prefix.